# How do I dynamically create a common proxy class of two unrelated classes?

Tags: java, code-generation, cglib, dynamic-class-loaders

I have two unrelated java classes (only `*.class`, no `*.java`) like this:

```
public class Trick {
    public String getName() { return "Jack"; }
    public String trick() { ... }
}
```

and

```
public class Treat {
    public String getName() { return "John"; }
    public String treat() { ... }
}
```

and I would like to generate a sort of *Proxy* class at runtime that represents the union of both classes and forwards them to the respective instance, and maybe throw if that's not possible. I assume that can be done with `cglib` but I don't know where to start.

This is what I would like to do (pseudocode):

```
// prepare: generate a common interface
TrickOrTreat trickOrTreat = magic.createUnionInterface(Trick.class, Treat.class);

// use with concrete interface A:
Trick trick = new Trick();
TrickOrTreat proxyA = magic.createProxy(trickOrTreat.class, trick);
System.out.println("trick name: " + proxyA.getName());

// use with concrete interface B:
Treat treat = new Treat();
TrickOrTreat proxyB = magic.createProxy(trickOrTreat.class, treat);
System.out.println("treat name: " + proxyB.getName());
```

Or something to that effect. I would like to do it completely dynamically, probably `cglib`-based? If thats not possible I would do it with a code generation step in between?

Comment: I don't understand, why do you want to do this dynamically? Since you have to write a TrickOrTreat interface statically anyway... As a guideline, cglib should only be used when you have no way of knowing the types of objects you will have at runtime, i.e only for library code.

Comment: @DLevant Hrm, yes. Since I want to write `TrickOrTreat` in my client source code I have to have that one as a class beforehand. You are right, it would not make sense, else. So I *have to have* a previous pass with a code generator. Ok, then `cglib` is not the right tool, but what is, then? `javaparser` has `*.java` as input, which I don't have. So... what way to go?

Comment: I still don't understand why you don't just write whatever it is you need by hand...

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to trade in cglib, you can do this with [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy). I typically refuse to call it magic but here you go:

```
class Magic {
    Class<?> createUnionInterface(Class<?> a, Class<?> b) {
        DynamicType.Builder<?> builder = new ByteBuddy().makeInterface();
        Set<MethodDescription.SignatureToken> tokens = new HashSet<>();
        for (MethodDescription m : new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(a)
                .getDeclaredMethods()
                .filter(ElementMatchers.isVirtual())) {
            tokens.add(m.asSignatureToken());
            builder = builder.defineMethod(m.getName(),
                    m.getReturnType(),
                    m.getModifiers()).withoutCode();
        }
        for (MethodDescription m : new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(b)
                .getDeclaredMethods()
                .filter(ElementMatchers.isVirtual())) {
            if (!tokens.contains(m.asSignatureToken())) {
                builder = builder.defineMethod(m.getName(),
                        m.getReturnType(),
                        m.getModifiers()).withoutCode();
            }
        }
        return builder.make()
                .load(Magic.class.getClassLoader())
                .getLoaded();
    }

    Object createProxy(Class<?> m, final Object delegate) throws Exception {
        return new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(m)
                .method(new ElementMatcher<MethodDescription>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean matches(MethodDescription target) {
                        for (Method method : delegate.getClass()
                               .getDeclaredMethods()) {
                            if (new MethodDescription.ForLoadedMethod(method)
                                   .asSignatureToken()
                                   .equals(target.asSignatureToken())) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(delegate))
                .make()
                .load(Magic.class.getClassLoader())
                .getLoaded()
                .newInstance();
    }
}
```

Note that you cannot reference a runtime-generated type at compile-time. This is however a given constraint with runtime code generation.

```
Magic magic = new Magic();

Class<?> trickOrTreat = magic.createUnionInterface(Trick.class, Treat.class);

Trick trick = new Trick();
Object proxyA = magic.createProxy(trickOrTreat, trick);
System.out.println("trick name: " + trickOrTreat.getDeclaredMethod("getName").invoke(proxyA));

Treat treat = new Treat();
Object proxyB = magic.createProxy(trickOrTreat, treat);
System.out.println("trick name: " + trickOrTreat.getDeclaredMethod("getName").invoke(proxyB));
```

You can overcome this by generating your `TrickOrTreat` class prior to runtime such that you can reference the type at runtime.

As for the suggested union-type approach, this would require you to have at least one class to be an interface type as Java does not support multiple inheritance.

Comment: I am getting a NoClassDefFoundError on the `.load(...)` line in `createProxy` with this example. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

- If you need functionality of both classes/interfaces you can use

```
public <TT extends Trick & Treat> void process(TT thing){
    //...
}
```

**edit:**

- Implement new Interface MyProxyHandler

```
public interface MyProxyHandler {}
```

- Extend it with interfaces of classes say TreatInterface and TrickInterface
- Create class ProxyManager that implements java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler

```
public abstract class ProxyManager<T extends MyProxyHandler> implements InvocationHandler {

    protected static String LOCK_OBJECT = new String("LOCK");

    protected T proxyHandler;
    protected List<T> handlers = new ArrayList<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ProxyManager(Class<T> _clazz) {
        proxyHandler = (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(_clazz.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{_clazz}, this);
    }

    public T getProxy() {
        return proxyHandler;
    }

    public List<T> getHandlers() {
        return handlers;
    }

    public void setHandlers(List<T> handlers) {
        this.handlers = handlers;
    }

    public boolean registerHandler(T handler) {
        synchronized (LOCK_OBJECT) {
            boolean add = true;
            for (T item : this.handlers) {
                if (item.getClass().equals(handler.getClass())) {
                    add = false;
                }
            }
            if (add)
                this.handlers.add(handler);
            return add;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        String result = "";
        for (MyProxyHandler handler : getHandlers()) {
            try {
                //I recommend that methods returns some enum like HANDLED/NOTHANDLED 
                result = (String) method.invoke(handler, args);
                if (result.equals("Some flag"))
                    break;
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw e.getCause();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

- Extend that class with your concrete class

```
public class TreatTrickProxyManager<T extends TreatInterface & TreatInterface> extends ProxyManager<T> {
     public TreatTrickProxyManager(Class<T> _clazz) {
          super(_clazz);
     }
}
```

- In your bussines logic class get an instance of TreatTrickProxyManager
- In your method

```
public void retrieveSomeData(){
     ((TreatTrickProxyManager)getTreatTrickProxyManager().getProxy()).someMethodInvocation()
}
```

Comment: That actually *is* amazing. I didn't know that. I will read up, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html. I can work with that, yes, but your *suggestion* is far from a solution. It only works with *interfaces* (or one interface and one class).

Comment: And, although the `&`-symbol is used the "calculates" the *union* (not the *intersection*) of the interfaces -- because it just expects that both interfaces are provided by `TT`. Its not quite what I need, but close and definitely useful.

Comment: I didn't have time to completely investigate your question. There is edit in my answer - it's a direction in which i would go to get functionalities that you seek.